# Strange Ionic Framework behavior with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have an `ng-repeat` with a button inside which calls a controller method.
I'm using the `Ionic Framework` which is based on `AngularJS`
I can't get the button to actually trigger the controller method unless I revert to using plain Angular (or one more variant, which I will show later).

My example of the broken situation can be seen [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcp7oqa1/3/).

You can see that the red button works (generates an alert) and the green, inside the `ng-repeat` doesn't, while it is calling the exact same controller function.

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
.controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

var answers = [];
addOptionToArray("Option 1");
addOptionToArray("Option 2");
addOptionToArray("Option 3");
$scope.answers = answers;

$scope.doSomething = function() {
  alert("clicked");
};

function addOptionToArray(optionText) {
  answers.push({text : optionText});
} 
}]);
```

and the page layout:

```
<div ng-app="todoApp">

<div ng-controller="TodoController">
<button class="button button-assertive"  ng-click="doSomething()">
    <i class="icon ion-minus-circled"></i>
</button>

<label class="item item-input item-button-right" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
<input type="text" ng-model="answer.text">
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="doSomething()">
    <div>click</div>
  </button>
</div>
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Now there are two thins that will make the button inside the `ng-repeat` work again

1. Replace the `Ionice` bundle JS reference with a pure `AngularJS' one as can be seen [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcp7oqa1/4/)
2. While keeping the Ionic JS reference, remove the `<input>'` inside the `ng-repeat` see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcp7oqa1/5/)

Any idea of why having the `<input>` inside the `ng-repeat` breaks the button's `ng-click`?
Or what is broken in `Ionic`?

Comment: Just noticed. It looks like (with Ionic) clicking the button sets the focus on the `<input>'. Maybe this is a clue

Comment: Now I see that the combination of <input> and a <button> doesn't work even outside on ng-repeat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with block elements inside inline elements. Don't put `<div>` inside `<button>` or `<label>`. Fix it and it works as expected:

```
<div ng-app="todoApp">
    <div ng-controller="TodoController">
        <a href="#" class="button button-assertive" ng-click="doSomething()"><i class="icon ion-minus-circled"></i></a>
        <div class="item item-input item-button-right" ng-repeat="answer in answers">
            <input type="text" ng-model="answer.text" />
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="button button-balanced" ng-click="doSomething()">Click</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still unclear why it worked with pure Angular, and failed under Ionic

Comment: Had the same problem, mine was a button inside a label for a search bar. Changed the label to a div and it worked perfectly. Thanks